# regarding integrating the WPF login app with winform system tray in a single solution file using C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a system tray (WinForms) and another project (WPF) and kept them in a single solution file. My requirement is to call the login app's startup event in my system tray login event, but the startup method is a protected function. I have tried several ways to solve this but have been unsuccessful. Can you suggest how to resolve this issue?

Comment: The question is unclear. What startup function? How did you create the tray icon and what do you mean by `login`? Is your *real* question how to execute a command through the tray icon's context menu? One that just happens to be called during startup as well? The answer is to put that code in a separate method and call that from your menu command, not try to call the startup code

Comment: It's unclear whether you have one or two applications so it's unclear whether you want to execute a menu command or make a cross-process call. You can use tray icons in WPF, there's no reason to have a separate WinForms application. You can even use the WinForms NotifyIcon component in your WPF application.

Comment: actually i have two types projects one is system tray project(WinForms) and another one is  related to one desktop applicatiion,but both projects in same solution file i kept.
so now my exact requiremnet is i want to open my desktop application login app in my system tray login event ....
how to call that dekstop application in my system tray login event ..?

Comment: Start the Desktop Application with a call to `Process.Start`?

Comment: i will provide you the my app.xaml.file then you can easily suggest me i think

Comment: You said the tray project is in WInforms so there should be no relevant app.xaml.

Comment: private void loginToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loginToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;


            lgoutToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;

            connectedToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;

            disconnectedToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
}
hear i need to call that desktop application startup function

Comment: Post the code in the question itself. `i have two types projects one is system tray project(WinForms) and another one is related to one desktop applicatiion,b...` that's the unclear part you already wrote in the question. Are those two separate executables? Why? Does the Winforms application exist only to display the icon? Why  not put the icon in the WPF and get rid of Winforms then? What `system tray login event`? Tray icons have nothing to do with logins, they display notifications and menus

Comment: yes correct in WinForms there is no any App.xaml.cs file ,
but i said for my desktop application ,it is in WPF .

Comment: You keep repeating the same unclear statements. I suspect you misunderstand how notification icons work in general, what they do and even what `login` means. Are you trying to add a tray icon when a user logs in? Tray icons are owned by applications, which means you need to start your app at startup. That app can be the WPF app only, started as a hidden app. Unless its startup is so heavy you want to have a small app for the tray that *starts* the heavy WPF app? Well, why not use `Process.Start` with the WPF executable's path?

Comment: the desktop application and system tray both are different projects but in a same solution file

Comment: I have a solution that contains two projects: a system tray WinForms project and a login app WPF project. In the system tray project, I want to call a protected method from the login app project when a login event occurs.

I have identified the main method/function in the login app project that I need to call. However, this method is protected, and I'm unsure how to access it from the system tray project.

Comment: Here's what I've tried so far:

I have added a reference to the login app project in the system tray project.
I have created an instance of the class that contains the protected method in the system tray project.
However, since the method is protected, I'm unable to call it directly.

Is there a way to call a protected method from one project in another project? What approach should I take to achieve this functionality? Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated.